# Are there infinitely many $n$ for which $\varphi(n)$ is a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Prove or disprove: $\phi(n)$ is a perfect square for only a finite number of odd numbers n.

I know it works for even numbers since we can use $n=p^k$ and have $p=2$, however, I don't know about odd numbers.

Comment: Disprove! Think about $p^k$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You might be thinking about $p=n^2+1$ problem, but here we need just one prime $p$ of the form.

Comment: @i707107 I'm still not sure what to do... I've been trying to use $p^k$

Comment: $5, 5^3, 5^5$, etc...

Comment: Hint: It's clear that you have to disprove as if $n^2+1$ is prime, then  $ϕ(n^2+1) = n^2$. There isn't a proof of such numbers are infinite, but it's one of the million dollar problems, and they're thought to be infinite. Then, there must be another proof not dealing with $n^2+1$.

Answer (score 5):

We know that if $p$ is a prime number and $k$ is an integer with $k ≥ 1$, then $φ(p^k) = p^k − p^{k−1}$
Consider $p = 2$. Then
$φ(2^k) = 2^k − 2^{k−1} = 2^{k−1} = 2^{2\frac{k-1}{2}}$
Thus $φ(2^k)$ is a perfect square whenever $k$ is odd. Thus, there are infinitely
many integers $n$ such that $φ(n)$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Nice post. Welcome to MSE. Check out [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn about mathjax.

Answer (score 2):

Take any $p=n^2+1$, $p$ is prime, $n>2$ is natural number. It's clear that $p$ is odd. Now, I have a lemma stating that $ \forall p = n^2+1, \phi(p^{2k+1})=(p-1)*p^{2k}$. Let's prove this lemma by induction:

For $k=0$ and $p=n^2+1$, as $p$ is prime, $\phi(p^{2k+1}) = \phi(p)= p-1$

Now, assume the lemma is true with k. Check out what's gonna happen with k+1?

$p^{2(k+1)+1} = p^{2k+3}$

Think about the numbers which divides $p^{2k+3}$. As $p$ is prime, the only numbers which are relatively prime with $p^{2k+3}$ are the ones that can be divided by $p$. We know that the number of the ones which are smaller than $p^{2k+1}$ is $(p-1)*p^{2k}$ with the assumption of induction. And the number of numbers between $p^{2k+1}$ and $p^{2k+3}$ is $p^{2k+3}-p^{2k+1}$, in total. The ratio of being relatively prime with $p^{2k+3}$ is $(p-1)/p$. Then the number of numbers which are not relatively prime with $p^{2k+3}$ and between $p^{2k+1}$ and $p^{2k+3}$ is:

$$[(p^{2k+3}-p^{2k+1})*(p-1)]/p$$
$$= [p^{2k+1}*(p^2-1)*(p-1)]/p $$
$$= p^{2k} *(p-1)^2 * (p+1) $$

Now add this to the number of the ones that smaller than $p^{2k+1}$, which is $(p-1)*p^{2k}$, we have:

$$[(p-1)*p^{2k}] + p^{2k} *(p-1)^2 * (p+1)$$
$$ =p^{2k}*(p-1)*[(p-1)*(p+1)+1] $$
$$ = p^2k*(p-1)*[p^2-1+1]$$
$$ = p^{2k}*(p-1)*p^2$$
$$ = p^{2k+2}*(p-1)$$
$$ = p^{2(k+1)}*(p-1)$$

This is the proof of the lemma.

Now, it's clear that $(p-1)*(p^{2k})=n^2*p^{2k}$ is a perfect square. If we assume that some number m is the maximum number such that $\phi(m)$ is a perfect square, because we could find a number $p^{2k+1} > m$ in every time, this assumption would be wrong. Then, ϕ(n) is a perfect square for infinitely many numbers of odd numbers n.

Example: $5$ is a prime number and $5=2^2+1$. Then, $\phi(5)$, $\phi(5^3)$, $\phi(5^5)$,.....,$\phi(5^{2k+1})$, .... are all perfect squares and they are infinitely many.

Comment: By the way, I have to add that I used @i707107 's comment on the question as a start point.

Comment: I don't think you need the lemma,it follows from the definition of the function

Answer (score 0):

Consider $5^{2m+1}17^{2n+1}$. Similarly, one could use $3^{2m+1}19^{2n+1}$. One can play the same game with $11$ and $41$. Or use $3^{2a+1}7^{2b+1}11^{2c+1}31^{2d+1}$.

**Remark:** It has been conjectured that there are infinitely many primes of the shape $x^2+1$. There is considerable numerical evidence that the conjecture is true. In that case there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $\varphi(p)$ is a perfect square.

Comment: But you cannot disprove a theorem with counting on a proposition that is not proved. From what you said, you can only think that you have to disprove the theorem, not prove.

Comment: The main answer gives an infinite collection of numbers with the required property. The remark is about a connection between a variant of that problem (are there infinitely many primes with that property). That is unknown.

Comment: But what is the rule that you select those numbers in the main answer? According to what rule did you select 5 and 17, and why are they infinitely many?

Comment: There are infinitely many because we can choose $m$ (and $n$) arbitrarily. So the first answer $5^{2m+1}17^{2n+1}$ already produces a "double infinity" of examples. The reason I thought of them is that I was thinking in terms of Fermat numbers, for no good reason. The other answers I give also each produce an infinite number of examples, since the exponents can be freely chosen, as long as they are odd.

Comment: Probably I'm not able to express myself =) First of all, how do you select 5 and 17, and what's the theorem you're using to show that $\phi(5^{2m+1}*17^{2n+1})$ is perfect square? I showed that if the prime you're using is in shape $p=x^2+1$, then $\phi(p^{2k+1})$ is perfect square, but where does $3^{2m+1}*19^{2n+1}$ come from? Is there a theorem for any semi-prime number, or how to select those?

Comment: By fooling around. We have $\varphi(p^{2k+1})=p^{2k}(p-1)$ (if $p$ is prime). The $p^{2k}$ part is good. Take for example $p=3$. Then $p-1=2$. We want to find another prime $q$ such that $q-1$ is twice a perfect square, so that $(p-1)(q-1)$ will be a perfect square. Note that $q=19$ works. So does $q=73$. The more complicated last example uses several primes $s,t,u,v$ chosen so that $(s-1)(t-1)(u-1)(v-1)$ is a perfect square. And then we take odd powers to get infinitely many examples. So one just experiments with primes $p$ such that $p-1$ has only "small" factors.

Comment: Now I got it. I just needed the supportive theorems and explanations. And I didn't know the theorem that you begin with, and I proved it for the primes which are $p=n^2+1$ only, as I did not notice that it was true for all integers. Anyway, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: There are also general construction procedures. Call a number $n$ good if $\varphi(n)$ is a perfect square. If $a$ and $b$ are good and **relatively prime** then because $\varphi$ is multiplicative, $ab$ must be good.

Answer (score 0):

The process of finding perfect squares among odd numbers, is similar to that of finding things perfect numbers.  I should imagine there are an infinite number of these things, though.

For example, the totient of 7 is 6.  You then just have to find eg a prime of the form $6n^2+1$, such as $97$, and the totient of $7\cdot 97$ is itself a square.  Also, since $601 = 6\cdot 10^2+1$, so is the product of any two of these numbers, like $4207$, which gives $60^2$.  These can be multiplied by any even power, such as $7^3$ has a totient of $7^2 \cdot 6$.

One notes that any prime of the form of $n^2+1$ has a square totient, as does multiplying this by any of the numbers found above.

Even if one supposes powers, one can find examples, like $3^2$, whose totient is 6.  Since these are identical with the previous example, then the totient of say $63$ is $6^2$, and so forth.